# Force a minimum number of instances

Tags: alloy

When running a model in alloy, you can define a maximum number of objects.

```
 // like this:
 run example for 10 MyElements
```

If you want exactly 10, you can write:

```
 run example for exactly 10 MyElements
```

But is there a way to force a minimum amount instead of a maximum ?
Or something like an interval ? This would make testing much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use cardinality constraints to force that. Something like

```
run {example and #MyElements>5} for 10 MyElements, 5 int
```

You need to be careful to set the integer bit-width to allow enough positive 
integers up to your scope.

Comment: thank you, this seems to work. Where did you get this information ?

Comment: You always need to have an upper bound in order to limit the scope of the analysis performed by the tool. Or you provide it, or it is 3 by default.

In this answer, Alcino simply runs the analysis with the additional constraint that both the example predicate and the fact that the number of elements (#) typed by the signature MyElements are striclty greater to 5, holds.